# Excel. Adding a formula to a cell with a SUMIF and a variable row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`Evening all. Just a quick one i'm sure to save me going back and forth forever with "s and &s

So i have some VBA code that is adding a Formula into a cell. The formula is using a sumif function to compare a time to a column of times and adding up the totals that are in a column a couple of doors down (but only the cells that are in the same column as the original time. I am currently toying with the following formula (and have been for quite a while) but i think my coding is just a little sub par and I'm struggling to get it to work in my current project, but I think I'm close :)

```
WS.[C14].Offset(i).Formula = "=SUMIF(times," & ActiveCell.Row & "*,proc)"
```

times and proc are named ranges where the times to check and the cells which will have the total to sum are, and the criteria (the actual time in the middle of the SUMIF) is being taken from the active row of the selected cell... which is being selected in some coding for a ForEach block as you can see below

```
For Each cel In Rng.Cells
WS.[A14].Offset(i).Select
WS.[B14].Offset(i) = WC.[H1].Offset(j)
WS.[C14].Offset(i).Formula = "=SUMIF(times," & ActiveCell.Row & "*,proc)"
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
```

Next cel
On Error Resume Next

The whole part of the VBA works fine, it's just that one formula in the C14 loop that just refuses to play right. Does anyone have any ideas on a suitable easy fix? Added below an image of the table below... with the result that I am after.

Just a point to note, i can't used set ranges as both tables are pretty dynamic in how many values they can both hold!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, or if more info is needed, then I'l be happy to help :) many thanks
[image]

Faffing for ages :/ hehe

Comment: What is the expected formula? With your current code, the output is something like `=SUMIF(times,5*,proc)`, which is not a valid formula.

Comment: Yeah, i've messed about with the code to the point of no return haha... =SUMIF(times,"="&B34,proc) is the code i have in a cell! But the B34 will need to be replaced with B & ActiveCell.Row... if that makes sense.... as it's being set using a .Formula= in my VBA scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess as to what you want:

```
WS.Range("C14").Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Formula = "=SUMIF(times,B14,proc)"
```

There is no need to loop. When you write a formula with relative (or mixed) references to a range, Excel will automatically update the references down rows and/or across columns.

Comment: Will this work within the ForEach cel in Range...? Because the cell ranges sem quite static. I made a breakthrough with WS.[C14].Offset(i).Formula = "=SUMIF(times," & ActiveCell.Row & ",proc)" which is working except for the column... its giving me =SUMIF(times,34,proc) / =SUMIF(times,35,proc) instead of =SUMIF(times,B34,proc) / =SUMIF(times,B35,proc)

Comment: Yes, there is no need to loop when you write a formula with a relative or mixed reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I managed to get it working with WS.[D14].Offset(i).Formula = "=SUMIF(times," & "B" & ActiveCell.Row & ",proc)" I know there is probably an easier way of doing it, or a more simpler way to code it! I'll be looking into streamlining my code once I know everything it working! Many thanks for your help though, much appreciated x <3